# How to pass bulk comma separated values as a parameter to Oracle stored procedure?

Tags: oracle, csv, stored-procedures, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to pass around 2000 comma separated values to an oracle stored procedure. My procedure looks something like this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SET_VALUES(V_VALUES IN VARCHAR2)
```

Now the variable `V_VALUES` is a string of 2000 comma separated values. What is the most effective way to pass that parameter? Creating a new table is out of options here for some reasons.

Comment: What is database character set ? What is 4 digits Oracle version ? What is the average size of a value ?

Comment: you mean you want to create 2000 separate rows from the one string? Please show an example of the string, the table definition, and expected results

Comment: @pifor the version is 12c r2. Average size for the value is around 10 characters.

Comment: @OldProgrammer I won't be creating seperate rows, but passing this much bigger string parameter sometimes breaks the further code. Is there any other way to do this rather than a string parameter?

Answer (score 1):

"The most effective way" depends on *who's asking*.

From my point of view, that would be exactly what you said: as a comma-separated values string.

- if you're passing it from PL/SQL, its length can be up to 32K as it is the maximum length of a `varchar2` string in PL/SQL
- if you're passing it from SQL, you're limited to 4K as it is the maximum length of a `varchar2` string in SQL

  - it means that you can pass some 2000 single letters or digits, but nothing more as "letter + comma" make 2 characters which multiplied by 2000 makes 4K

The next point of view says: what do you plan to do with such a string? It is ineffective to do *anything* with it. As if you planned to use it in stored procedure's query, in its `WHERE` clause as `IN`. Sadly, it won't work *just like that* - you'll have to split it to rows. There are techniques so no problem about it; just saying.

Therefore, I'd rather store those 2000 values into a table and use it in a procedure in the most convenient way - by joining it to other table(s).

As I said, it *depends*.

---

Alternatively, if you aren't restricted to `varchar2` datatype as an input parameter, try `CLOB` instead:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure p_test (par_c in clob) as
  2  begin
  3    null;
  4  end;
  5  /

Procedure created.

SQL>
```

Comment: splitting and other things are done. Problem here is actually the data type which is unable to hold this amount of data. Your answer is absolutely correct but sadly creating another table is out of options as it doesn't fit in design. That's why I'm searching for some other options.

Comment: Can you pass a CLOB, then?

Comment: Yes we can try that. Does oracle stored procedure allow CLOB as input parameter?

Comment: Yes, it does. See an example I posted above.

Comment: While trying to execute the procedure I'm getting the 'PLS-00172: string literal too long' error with clob.